# Выполнение PHP скрипта после отправки формы

Tags: php

Как выполнить скрипт после отправки формы? (Условие : То что скрипт включен в index.html и там же должен быть выполнен)
Спасибо!

Comment: @VLADPRO100LORD, Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @mountpoint Я сделал уже готовую форму и имею скрипт на руках,но меня интересует как делать это без редиректа.

Comment: без специальных телодвижений по настройке вебсервера в html файлах не будет выполняться php скрипт. ответ - никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function Func(){
          alert("Форма отправлена!");
     }
</script>
<form action="" method="POST" onSubmit="Func();">
     <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
     <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Сорри не дочитал вопрос...

Дополняю:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["name"])) 
{
    // Выполняете скрипт
}
?>
<form action="" method="GET">
     <input type="text" name="name" />
     <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Так что ли? Вопрос не понимаю...

Comment: @AAT,
Выполнение PHP скрипта после отправки формы.Читайте.

Comment: @AAT,вроде бы вы ответили правильно.

Comment: @AAT не то что мне нужно было...